# Ansible : what is default password for the new user created using Ansible 'user' module

Tags: ansible

I am running a ansible-playbook template from another user, which has a task to create a new user:-

```
---

- name: Create the application user
  user: name={{ gunicorn_user }} state=present

- name: Create the application group
  group: name={{ gunicorn_group }} system=yes state=present

- name: Add the application user to the application group
  user: name={{ gunicorn_user }} group={{ gunicorn_group }} state=present
```

Here there is no password set for this user.
The new user is created in system after running the playbook.
But when I try to login using the newly created user, it is asking for password?

basically, rather than logging in using the new account, my intention is to understand how/why is it asking for a password? since I did not specify a password while creating user.

I checked in /etc/passwd :-

it shows `youtubeadl:x:1003:999::/home/youtubeadl:`

`youtubeadl` is the new user created

Comment: I made a post that may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660540/passwords-in-user-module-ansible

Answer (score 8):

If you leave out the `password` parameter for the `user` task, Ansible will create the used in a "locked" state, meaning the user has no password. She will not be able to login with a password, use a password for sudo commands or change her password.

But since you did not provide an alternative method of login authentication (e.g. an SSH key with an additional [`authorized_key`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) task), you will still be asked for a password.

**Background Info**:

You can have a look at the password state youself, by looking at  `/etc/shadow` (which stores the password info), not `/etc/passwd` (which, despite the name, stores only user account info). See https://serverfault.com/a/116511/39608 for a history of those two files.

The entry will probably look like this:

```
youtubeadl:!:0:0:99999:7:::
```

The `!` in the 2nd field means the password is locked. If you issue the command

```
passwd -d youtubeadl
```

You will set the password to empty and the password state to "expired". The entry will then look like this:

```
youtubeadl::0:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: I have created a user without explicitly specifying a password and I can not log in using SSH either, message in `/var/log/auth.log`: `User <name> not allowed because account is locked`. By the looks of it, when omitting the password, Ansible creates a user that can not log in neither using password nor SSH key.

Comment: Also note that crypted passwords can be backed up, restored, and transferred to other machines. When a password is set, instead of `!` it looks like `$6$LgUYFDdu$4AN4zqSU.aox.EMD7qYL71uMSObEn0PC8hUC9xcfjkXPZCeEy6CZY8WvfgV5Cusx6RXboiVM0bnKeoF40Y.q5/`. (This one uses SHA-512 hashing, as indicated by the `6` in the first field.)

Answer (score 0):

Ansible's user module uses useradd under the covers which by default disables the password if a password is not specified. You should be able to confirm that by checking the user's entry in `/etc/passwd` - if the password is disabled then the password field should show `!!`.

If you want to login directly as that user using a password then you need to specify the password in the `user` module.

Alternatively you can add an SSH key using the `authorized_keys` module.

And of course, as long as the user has a proper shell set, then you should be able to `su` to that user from root (or with sudo from a non root user).

Comment: I checked in /etc/passwd :- it shows      youtubeadl:x:1003:999::/home/youtubeadl:

Comment: basically, rather than logging in using the new account, my intention is to understand how/why is it asking for a password? since I did not specify a password while creating user.

Comment: I'm just on my phone now so can't check it out exactly but I'm pretty sure that it always prompts for a password on a login even if you explicitly pass the disable password parameter to useradd